# Why i am getting error in Nusphere PHPed?

Tags: php, wamp, phped

I am getting this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW, expecting '(' in C:\wamp\www\common.php on line 15

and the line 15 is

```
$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');
```

but when i run in wamp then it's run fine without any error.
so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` constant is only available when the mysqlnd driver is used. I guess Nysphere doesn't have that driver enabled.

See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47224

Also search SO for other questions related to `MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND`